# (Python) If statement to always search for specific class name to be true and present and only then will it run the code below it

Tags: python, class, if-statement, xpath

I have been struggling on this for a while.

I want it to always be searching for this class name and trigger the code below it when the class is found. I dont want the script below it to be active until the class name is present. Until a pop up box is present for example.

I am using selenium and webdriver.

I am trying to make this work:

```
while true:
time.sleep(random.randint(2,3))
if driver.find_element_by_class_name("recaptcha-checkbox-border"):
#driver.refresh()
#time.sleep(random.randint(2,3))
#switch to recaptcha frame
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.getcwd()+"\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe") 
    delay()
    frames=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
    driver.switch_to.frame(frames[0]);
    delay()
    #click on checkbox to activate recaptcha
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("recaptcha-checkbox-border").click()
    
    #switch to recaptcha audio control frame
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    frames=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]").find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
    driver.switch_to.frame(frames[0])
    delay()
    
    #click on audio challenge
    driver.find_element_by_id("recaptcha-audio-button").click()
    
    #switch to recaptcha audio challenge frame
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    frames= driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
    driver.switch_to.frame(frames[-1])
    delay()
```

Comment: I'm assuming ```driver.find_element_by_class_name("rc-anchor-pt")``` will return true when the class is found?

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    sleep(10)
    #driver.refresh()
    #time.sleep(random.randint(2,3))
    if driver.find_element_by_class_name("rc-anchor-pt"):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div/button").click()
        #get the mp3 audio file
        src = driver.find_element_by_id("audio-source").get_attribute("src")
        print("[INFO] Audio src: %s"%src)
        #download the mp3 audio file from the source
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, os.getcwd()+"\\sample.mp3")
        sound = pydub.AudioSegment.from_mp3(os.getcwd()+"\\sample.mp3")
        sound.export(os.getcwd()+"\\sample.wav", format="wav")
        sample_audio = sr.AudioFile(os.getcwd()+"\\sample.wav")
        r= sr.Recognizer()
        break
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Whenever I get a captcha prompt is still doesn't get triggered.

I have updated the post to show how I implemented it.

Comment: Glad I could help you make some progress but I'm not familiar with the packages you are using for this so I don't think I'll be much help from here on. I will say that it might be difficult to by-pass captchas if that what you're trying to do.  They're tests to make sure that users are human so that sites don't get spammed by bots.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I have actually successfully bypassed the captcha by using the audio option and converting that to text to then be automatically entered. 

My issue is that it currently runs at the beginning and if the captcha isn't there from the start it wont run again later. It is often the case that it will run later and not the start ahaha.